# Universal App with target 'Release' fails with compiler error ILT0021 Method Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation not found

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, win-universal-app

my small Universal App Project with build target 'Release' fails with compiler error ILT0021 Method System.Nullable Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.get_DiagonalSizeInInches not found. Very strange the Build target 'Debug' shows no problem

Using

Windows 10

Visual Studio 2015

Build target 'Release x468'

Comment: I nailed it down. It's the combination of  the project template (template10) and the 'Compile with the native .NET Native toolchain' .

Standard Visual Studio UWP project template is working with native toolchain but not the project template from template10. See https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/issues/607

Comment: Hi there, so what is the workaround? can you post it as answer?